# Magento - How to upload image with dynamic url?

Tags: image, magento

I need to upload images for my magento website with dynamic URL. My images are stored in another website folder. I need to access those images dynamically for my website.

Please guide  me on this. Thanks every in advance.

Comment: Could you clarify?  Is this for a product? And you want to reference the image from another folder (outside the Magento root?) Do you need to see this in the admin, r only on the frontend?

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply.No, only for images  and yes , The images folder location belongs to another website folder. Both admin and frontend need to see the image.